# Splliting the string data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to process the following data in dataframe df

[image: Imput data]

I want a function similar to delimit in excel, so that i can delimit by - and / . The output should be like

[image: Output data]

Please help me with the code for achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a regex pattern to do this and pass to [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract just the word without extraneous characters:

```
In [15]:    
df['str_code'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=True)

Out[15]:
1                      OS
2                      OC
3    ABOFS16AWWWTP1034102
4                 stories
5                  search
6    ABOFA15AWWWTP1075401
Name: str_code, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think you can add `expand=False`

Comment: I am not getting the correct result using this command.
so i used
df['str_code'] =df['str_code'].str.strip('/').str.split('-').str[0].str.split('/').str[0]

Comment: You'll have to post sample data that shows where this doesn't work

Comment: I think in my version,  expand is not working. The code works by removing expand
df['URL']=df['URL'].str.extract('(\w+)')

Answer (score 0):

df['URL']=df['URL'].str.extract('(\w+)')

This is the better way

Answer (score -1):

df['str_code'] =df['str_code'].str.strip('/').str.split('-').str[0].str.split('/').str[0]

This works

Comment: Please check my answer, maybe can works too. I firstly delete it, beause I think Edchum answer can solve your problem better.

Comment: Edchum way was better, only we need to remove expand=True
df['URL']=df['URL'].str.extract('(\w+)')